# Linguistic Analysis API authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, analysis, linguistics, azure-cognitive-services

**H**ello! Did anybody use *Linguistic Analysis API* (one of *The Microsoft Cognitive Services*) in your c# project? I have a problem with the authentication method, and there is not enough information in the net to solve my issue. A small example would be very helpful! Thank you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a github project specifically to help c# programmers consume APIs from all available AI services (Microsoft, Google, IBM BlueMix, Houndify, Wit). It includes Microsoft's *Linguistic Analysis API*.

https://github.com/BSalita/Woundify